# Validating CollectionView items for type matching during DragGesture action. .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

So, I have an animal model:

```
 public class Animal
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string? Name { get; set; }

     public string? ImageRoute { get; set; }

     public string? SoundRoute { get; set; }
 }
```

And service class, that set three random animals

```
private readonly HashSet<Animal> returnedAnimals = new HashSet<Animal>();

public IEnumerable<Animal> GetThreeAnimals()
{
    if (returnedAnimals.Count >= animals.Count() - 3)
    {
        returnedAnimals.Clear();
    }

    var availableAnimals = animals.Except(returnedAnimals);

    var randomAnimals = availableAnimals
        .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Take(3);

    foreach (var animal in randomAnimals)
    {
        returnedAnimals.Add(animal);
    }

    return randomAnimals;
}
```

**So, I need to somehow implement a drag mechanism for each image within a collection**, here:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding animals}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                           ItemSpacing="15"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Animal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageRoute}"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   WidthRequest="120">
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**And drop images in border's image:**

```
<Border Grid.Column="0"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        WidthRequest="125"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
        Stroke="BlueViolet"
        StrokeThickness="4">

    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True"
                   DragOver="OnDragOver"
                   Drop="OnDrop"/>
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
    
    <Grid RowDefinitions=".25*,.5*,.25*"
          Padding="10">
        
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding animals[0].Letter}"
               TextColor="BlueViolet"
               FontSize="28"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

        <Image Grid.Row="1"
               HeightRequest="130"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="End"
               Aspect="Fill"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding animals[0].Name}"
               Grid.Row="2"
               TextColor="BlueViolet"
               FontSize="20"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               VerticalOptions="End"/>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

So, my main question is **which Animal property use to bind to?** **And how to catch this property inside Border? Or is it better to implement OnDrop inside Grid's Image?**

I will be glad to have any help and information

Comment: Oh! And main logical task - Check if the dragged object (in my case a image) coincides with what is inside the border (some property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to drag the CollectionView Item to the Image area. So instead of adding the `GestureRecognizer` to the Border, you should add the `GestureRecognizer` to the Image in the Border,

*Here is the code for the Image control in Border and you could set the Height and Width for it*

```
            <Image Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    Aspect="Fill">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True"                           
                            DropCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            DropCommand="{Binding DropCommand}"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
```

And you want to check if the CollectionView Item the user choose is right, I think there are some ways to achieve. For example,

```
<ContentPage 
             ...
             x:Name="this">


<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Animal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageRoute}"
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               WidthRequest="120"
               HeightRequest="120">
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <DragGestureRecognizer
                            CanDrag="True"                                    
                            DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragStartingCommand ,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                            DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}"                                    
                            />
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

You could see in the CollectionView, I set `DragStartingCommand` which is implemented in the ViewModel. Each time we start dragging an item, we get it and set the value to `DragItem` in ViewModel.

```
    public Animal DragItem { get; set; }

    public Command DragStartingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                DragItem = e as Animal;
            });
        }
    }
```

Then we could implement our drop Command to check if the drag item coincides with what is inside the Border,

```
    public Command DropCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                if(DragItem.Name == animals[0].Name)
                {
                    // do something

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you! 

But could you please explain this snippet:
                            CanDrag="True"                                    
                            DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.DragStartingCommand,Source={x:Reference this}}"
                            DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}"                                    
                            />

Why do we need to use Source if we've already bound this command to an image?  And we set that image with our parameter, right?  So why do we need a Source?

Comment: Do you mean ```Source={x:Reference this}}"```? That because we use bindings in the DateTemplate. The default BindingContext is each item in the animals. But we want to bind the command  in the ViewModel. I set the name of the ContentPage to 'this'. You can see my updates in my answer.